# IN and IF operators in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, syntax, plsql

I'm trying to do (in PL/SQL)

```
if ((var1, var2) in ( select number1, number2 from.......) ) then
....
end if;
```

Why does this not work?
How would be the right thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that in PL/SQL you have to read (`select`) something into variables and then use it in an `IF` statement. You could do this in various ways but you cannot do this within the `IF` clause. Chorel's answer is quite inventive on this and he deserves some praise for the answer.

You could also just do

```
declare
  l_count number;
  var1 number := 1; -- or whatever the number
  var2 number := 2;
begin
  select count(*) 
    into l_count
    from mytable
   where number1 = var1 and number2 = var2;
  if l_count > 0 then
     ... the row exists
  end if;
end;
```

But the following **does not work**

```
if (select count(*) from mytable where (number1,number2) in (1,2)) > 0 then -- WRONG
    ...
end if;
```

If you want to use the `in` functionality you have to resort to table `dual`

```
   where (number1, number2) in (select var1, var2 from dual);
```

Like this

```
declare
  l_count number;
  var1 number := 1; -- or whatever the number
  var2 number := 2;
begin
  select count(*) 
    into l_count
    from mytable
   where (number1, number2) in (select var1, var2 from dual);
  if l_count > 0 then
     ...
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
declare
  l_exist number(1);
  var1 ...
  var2 ...
begin
  --obtain var1 & var2 
  -- ...
  select 
    case 
      when exists(select1 from ...
                  where number1 = var1 and number2 = var2) then 1
      else 0
    end into l_exist
  from dual;

  if l_exist = 1 
  then
    -- do what you want here
  end if;
end;
```